# When does MS-SQL maintain table indexes?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-performance

For arguments sake, lets say it's for SQL 2005/8.  I understand that when you place indexes on a table to tune `SELECT` statements, these indexes need maintaining during `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` actions.

My main question is this:

***When will SQL Server maintain a table's indexes?***

I have many subsequent questions:

I naively assume that it will do so after a command has executed.  Say you are inserting 20 rows, it will maintain the index after 20 rows have been inserted and committed.

- What happens in the situation where a
  script features multiple statements
  against a table, but are otherwise
  distinct statements?
- Does the server have the intelligence
  to maintain the index after all
  statements are executed or does it do
  it per statement?

I've seen situations where indexes are dropped and recreated after large / many `INSERT` / `UPDATE` actions.

- This presumably incurs rebuilding the
  entire table's indexes even if you
  only change a handful of rows?
- Would there be a performance benefit
  in attempting to collate `INSERT` and
  `UPDATE` actions into a larger batch,
  say by collecting rows to insert in a
  temporary table, as opposed to doing
  many smaller inserts?
- How would collating the rows above stack up against dropping an index versus taking the maintenance hit?

Sorry for the proliferation of questions - it's something I've always known to be mindful of, but when trying to tune a script to get a balance, I find I don't actually know when index maintenance occurs.

**Edit:** I understand that performance questions largely depend on the amount of data during the insert/update and the number of indexes.  Again for arguments sake, I'd have two situations:

- An index heavy table tuned for
  selects.
- An index light table (PK).

Both situations would have a large insert/update batch, say, 10k+ rows.

**Edit 2:** I'm aware of being able to profile a given script on a data set.  However, profiling doesn't tell me why a given approach is faster than another.  I am more interested in the theory behind the indexes and where performance issues stem, not a definitive "this is faster than that" answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question.  For  the second part, it will entirely depend on the number and content of the indexes as to whether it is faster to drop and rebuild or just update on top of the indexes.  Like most things in SQL, there is no answer or method that is correct 100% of the time.

Comment: @JNK I presumed as much, I am hoping someone can ball-park the situation or explain in what situations a given approach starts to become expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your statement (not even transaction) is completed, all your indexes are up-to-date. When you commit, all the changes become permanent, and all locks are released. Doing otherwise would not be "intelligence", it would violate the integrity and possibly cause errors.

Edit: by "integrity" I mean this: once committed, the data should be immediately available to anyone. If the indexes are not up-to-date at that moment, someone may get incorrect results.

As you are increasing batch size, your performance originally improves, then it will slow down. You need to run your own benchmarks and find out your optimal batch size. Similarly, you need to benchmark to determine whether it is faster to drop/recreate indexes or not.

Edit: if you insert/update/delete batches of rows in one statement, your indexes are modified once per statement. The following script demonstrates that:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Num(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Num(n)
SELECT 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 1;
GO
-- 0 updates to 1, 1 updates to 0
UPDATE dbo.Num SET n = 1-n;
GO
-- doing it row by row would fail no matter how you do it
UPDATE dbo.Num SET n = 1-n WHERE n=0;
UPDATE dbo.Num SET n = 1-n WHERE n=1;
```

Comment: I would have thought data integrity didn't apply to an index.  Is this only in the case of unique constraints?

Comment: If the index doesn't have integrity it's pretty much useless.  I'm not sure what would happen if SQL used an index to find a record that SHOULD be  there but that record was not.  I'm guessing you would get false negatives, which pretty much defeats the purpose of ACID.

Comment: So the index is maintained on a by-row basis as the values are inserted / updated? Ie, they automatically land in the correct location based on any indexes and the indexes are amended where needed? So even if row inserts are batched together, there should be no discernible difference versus multiple smaller inserts?  Come to think of it, I suppose there is overhead with committed index changes and table locking...

Comment: @Adam - I think you can negate some of the overhead with locking hints.  I normally do batch updates because it is faster (if you do as Alex says and tweak batch size by experimenting) and because if you have a failure you don't lose the whole statement.

Comment: nice explanation on the per statement part, I suspected this was the case but never really considered that after your statement finishes, even though your script may not have finished, someone else could concurrently come in and access the data.